# How to set string (or AnsiString) constant in the TVarRec?

Tags: string, delphi, constant-expression, open-array-parameters

I want to pass the formatting arguments `Args` into the [Format](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.Format) function.
I found some examples of that, but I can't find out how to assign string constant in the [TVarRec](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.TVarRec) member. The following code fails on compilation with `E2089 Invalid typecast`.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var Arguments: array of TVarRec;
begin
  SetLength(Arguments, 2);

  Arguments[0].VInteger := 111;
  Arguments[1].VAnsiString :=  PAnsiString('Text'); // I want to set this member

  ShowMessage(Format('Decimal: %d, String: %s', Arguments));
end;
```

Can anyone suggest me how to set the string (or AnsiString) constant to the TVarRec member ? I'm using Delphi 2009.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Relevant article for people who have never seen this hairy aspect of Delphi before: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html

Comment: I wrote an answer and deleted it, and someone else did too. This one was HARD.  Good one TOndrej.

Comment: Just for the record: You don't have to do all of that. You can call Format directly (and much more easily): `ShowMessage(Format('Decimal: %d, String: %s', [111, 'Text']));`. This works anywhere `TVarArgs` is called for (typically for an `array of const`) - you can create the `VarArgs` array by just passing it as `[StringItem, IntegerItem, BooleanItem]` and so forth.

Comment: You're right however I was considering to pass the `Args` as an `array of string` with variable length as the arguments to the `Format` function.

Comment: I figured you had a reason to want to do it this way (which is why I posted a comment and not an answer). I just didn't want someone new to Delphi to see your post and think this was the "normal" way to call `Format`.

Comment: You're right, but hard to say if the one notice the comment prior to the accepted answer; however still would be fine to rephrase it to the common way using own function instead of `Format`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to work in XE:

```
var
  Args: array[0..1] of TVarRec;
  S: AnsiString;
  U: UnicodeString;
begin
  S := 'Hello';
  U := 'world';
  Args[0].VType := vtAnsiString;
  Args[0].VAnsiString := Pointer(S);
  Args[1].VType := vtUnicodeString;
  Args[1].VUnicodeString := Pointer(U);

  Writeln(Format('%s, %s!', Args));
end;
```

Comment: +1 and accept. This works also in Delphi 2009. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Type-casting `Pointer(S)` should also work (thus allowing for empty strings). Seems the problem is merely with string literals.

Comment: I've modified the code to show both AnsiString and UnicodeString args.

Comment: Wow. That was harder than I thought it would be!  Another previous deleted answer used SetLength on an Array of TVarRec, and that appears to fail at runtime, even though it compiles okay. I was surprised by that.

Comment: That's what I've tried for the first time, but because I missed to add a `VType` I was getting an access violation. Thanks to all !

Comment: daemon_x: Pay careful attention to the difference between "array of TVarRec" which requires setLength, and array[0..1] which is fixed. Only the latter will work.

Comment: @Warren P - no, it works fine even if you use dynamic arrays; at least in D2009

Comment: Really?  So it was something about vtString versus vtUnicodeString that broke the other answer?

Answer (score 6):

Just my two cents. TOndrej's answer is correct, but I just wanted to emphasize some points. And comments are not a good place to do it.

Please be aware that the `AnsiString` must be referenced during all time `TVarRec` will be used.

For instance, if you write a function setting an array of `TVarRec`, you should ensure that you made a temporary copy of the `AnsiString` created within the function to a variable which will remain until all time the `TVarRec` array is used. Otherwise you may have some random access violation (not every time, but only when the MM reassign the `ansistring` memory).

For instance, the following code is **incorrect**:

```
type
  TVarRec2 = array[0..1] of TVarRec;

procedure SetVarRec(a,b: integer; var Result: TVarRec2);
begin
  Result[0].VType := vtAnsiString;
  Result[0].VString := pointer(AnsiString(IntToStr(a)));
  Result[1].VType := vtUnicodeString;
  Result[1].VString := pointer(UnicodeString(IntToStr(b)));
end;
```

Because the `AnsiString` and `UnicodeString` temporary variables will be freed when the procedure ends, and `Results[].VString` will still point to those freed memory...

Using a class or a record with some temporary private string may do the trick:

```
type
  TMyVar2 = record
  private
    tmpA: AnsiString;
    tmpB: UnicodeString; 
  public
    VarRec: TVarRec2;
    procedure SetVarRec(a,b: integer);
  end;

procedure TMyVar2.SetVarRec(a,b: integer);
begin
  VarRec[0].VType := vtAnsiString;
  tmpA := AnsiString(IntToStr(a));
  VarRec[0].VString := pointer(tmpA);
  VarRec[1].VType := vtUnicodeString;
  tmpB := UnicodeString(IntToStr(b));
  VarRec[1].VString := pointer(tmpB);
end;
```

Of course, in your program you may have an already existing class. In this case, you would better use a method, and some private temporary strings. For the method to be multi-thread safe (i.e. re-entrant) you should provide the temporary strings as parameters...

I use this trick to have valid a dynamic array of `TVarData` containing some `AnsiString` content in a class. In fact, `TVarData` and  `TVarRec` both uses such non referenced pointer to strings, which can be confusing.

Be aware that issues involving `pointer(S)` like statements can be difficult to track.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use array of ansistring value because you have to use point

```
temps: array of AnsiString;
value: array of TVarRec;
...
max_count := 10;
setlength(temps,max_count);
setlength(value,max_count);
for i := 0 to max_count-1 do begin
  temps[i] := IntToStr(i);
  value[i].VType := vtAnsiString;
  value[i].VString := Pointer(temps[i]); 
end;
AdoTable.insertrecord(value);
```